# Append to list of lists in for loop

Tags: r

I have a two data frames:

```
data<-structure(list(sample = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
                                              2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("S1", "S2"), class = "factor"), chrom = structure(c(1L,
                                                                                                                          1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("2L", "2R"), class = "factor"),
                         pos = c(318351L, 605574L, 1014043L, 2031592L, 2886957L, 2910379L,
                                 2218351L, 105574L, 1344043L, 216957L)), .Names = c("sample",
                                                                                    "chrom", "pos"), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")

> arrange(data, chrom,sample)

   sample chrom     pos
1      S1    2L  318351
2      S1    2L 2218351
3      S2    2L  605574
4      S2    2L 1014043
5      S2    2L  105574
6      S2    2L 1344043
7      S1    2R 2031592
8      S1    2R 2886957
9      S1    2R 2910379
10     S2    2R  216957
```

---

```
svBreaks<-structure(list(sample = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L,
                                              1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("S1", "S2"), class = "factor"), chrom = structure(c(1L,
                                                                                                                          1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("2L", "2R"), class = "factor"),
                         bp = c(2425901L, 2426025L, 6694426L, 6694566L, 8387755L,
                                8387927L, 8963713L, 963799L, 980364L, 980521L), gene = structure(c(3L,
                                                                                                   3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("CG8213",
                                                                                                                                                   "CG8216", "intergenic", "pdm3", "Tsp"), class = "factor"),
                         type = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L
                         ), .Label = c("DEL", "DUP", "INV", "TANDUP"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA,
                                                                                                         10L), .Names = c("sample", "chrom", "bp", "gene", "type"), class = "data.frame")

> arrange(svBreaks, chrom, sample)

 sample chrom      bp       gene   type
1      S1    2L 2425901 intergenic    DUP
2      S1    2L 2426025 intergenic    DEL
3      S1    2L 6694426        Tsp    DUP
4      S2    2L 6694566        Tsp    DEL
5      S2    2L 8387755       pdm3    INV
6      S2    2L 8387927       pdm3    INV
7      S1    2R 8963713     CG8216    INV
8      S1    2R  963799     CG8216 TANDUP
9      S1    2R  980521     CG8213    INV
10     S2    2R  980364     CG8213 TANDUP
```

And a function that calculates the distance between `pos` in `data` and `bp` in `svBreaks` on the same `chrom` for each sample:

```
fun3 <- function(p) {
  index<-which.min(abs(sv_df$bp - p))
  closestBp<-as.numeric(sv_df$bp[index])
  chrom<-as.character(sv_df$chrom[index])
  gene<-as.character(sv_df$gene[index])
  sample<-as.character(sv_df$sample[index])
  type<-as.character(sv_df$type[index])

  dist<-(p-closestBp)
  list(p, closestBp, dist, chrom, gene, type, sample)
}
```

I want to loop through each `chrom`, and call the function for each `sample` and build a data frame containing all `sample`s and `chrom`s. Here's what I've got so far:

```
l <- list()

for (c in levels(data$chrom)){
  for (s in levels(data$sample)){
    # Filter in chromosome and sample
    df<-filter(data, chrom == c & sample == s)
    sv_df<-filter(svBreaks, chrom == c & sample == s)

    # Apply funciton
    dist2bp<-lapply(df$pos, fun3)

    dist2bp<-do.call(rbind, dist2bp)
    dist2bp<-as.data.frame(dist2bp)

    colnames(dist2bp)=c("snp", "closest_bp", "min_dist", "chrom", "closest_gene", "type", "sample")
    l[[s]] <- dist2bp
  }
}
```

However, this does not give me the expected output, and only saves the second level of `chrom` - here's the resulting data frame:

```
> levels(data$chrom)
[1] "2L" "2R"
> levels(data$sample)
[1] "S1" "S2"

         snp closest_bp min_dist chrom closest_gene   type sample
S1.1 2031592     980521  1051071    2R       CG8213    INV     S1
S1.2 2886957     980521  1906436    2R       CG8213    INV     S1
S1.3 2910379     980521  1929858    2R       CG8213    INV     S1
S2    216957     980364  -763407    2R       CG8213 TANDUP     S2
```

---

If I also add to the list in the `chrom` loop, the output is also not correct:

```
for (c in levels(data$chrom)){
  for (s in levels(data$sample)){
    [...]
    l[[s]] <- dist2bp
  }
  l[[c]] <- dist2bp
}

snp closest_bp min_dist chrom closest_gene   type sample
S1.1 2031592     980521  1051071    2R       CG8213    INV     S1 # Chrom level 2, S1
S1.2 2886957     980521  1906436    2R       CG8213    INV     S1
S1.3 2910379     980521  1929858    2R       CG8213    INV     S1
S2    216957     980364  -763407    2R       CG8213 TANDUP     S2 # Chrom level 2, S2
2L.1  605574    6694566 -6088992    2L          Tsp    DEL     S2 # Chrom level 1, S2
2L.2 1014043    6694566 -5680523    2L          Tsp    DEL     S2
2L.3  105574    6694566 -6588992    2L          Tsp    DEL     S2
2L.4 1344043    6694566 -5350523    2L          Tsp    DEL     S2
2R    216957     980364  -763407    2R       CG8213 TANDUP     S2 # Not sure why this is here, # Chrom level 1, S1 is missing
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is `sv_df` in your function the `svBreaks` data frame?

Comment: @Sotos - Yes, in each loop iteration I'm filtering for `chrom` and `sample`: `sv_df<-filter(svBreaks, chrom == c & sample == s)`